# RefineryCMS installation problems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I installed the ruby refinerycms gem tonight in trying to play with a new system besides the normal WordPress or Drupal CMS'.

I ran `sudo gem install refinerycms` and it installed just fine. When I ran `sudo refinerycms /path/to/project` to create my new `refinerycms` project I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: activesupport(3.0.4 not = 3.0.3) (Gem::LoadError)
```

I uninstalled activesupport and installed 3.0.3 but I received the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: activesupport(3.0.3 not = 3.0.4) (Gem::LoadError)
```

So I'm really confused as to why this refinerycms gem won't install my new app. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Ruby (Rails) environment:
Ruby Version: `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]`
Rails Version: `Rails 3.0.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a tip -  don't use 'sudo' when you run the refinerycms command, it makes things far harder to manage within your application. (You can use it when installing the gem, though for ease I recommend [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com))

I believe I already answered this question on the RefineryCMS google group (if that didn't work, please reply there with additional feedback and we can get it worked out):

http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/52d9b215444f218b

Cheers,

Phil

Comment: @pamdt — Thanks for the reply! I uninstalled activesupport (ALL versions) and uninstalled the refinerycms gem. Reinstalled the refinerycms gem (it automatically installed activesupport 3.0.4). I ran `refinerycms Projects/refinerycms` and got the following error `/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: activesupport(3.0.4 not = 3.0.3) (Gem::LoadError)`... I am going to try the RVM link you sent next

Comment: I'll be releasing another version of RefineryCMS in the coming minutes that doesn't rely on activesupport in the installer as this isn't the first report I've had about this issue. It will be version 0.9.9.2.

Comment: — I uninstalled both versions of activesupport, reinstalled activesupport version 3.0.3 and ran refinerycms /path/to/project and got the following error `/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:238:in `activate': can't activate activesupport (= 3.0.3, runtime) for ["rails-3.0.3", "refinerycms-core-0.9.9.1", "refinerycms-authentication-0.9.9.1", "refinerycms-0.9.9.1"], already activated activesupport-3.0.4 for ["activerecord-3.0.4", "globalize3-0.1.0.beta", "refinerycms-core-0.9.9.1", "refinerycms-authentication-0.9.9.1", "refinerycms-0.9.9.1"] (Gem::LoadError)` — is this something new?

Comment: Yes, this was an issue. Please install refinerycms gem version 0.9.9.3